# Is HashSet good over List when dealing with a database with no duplicates?

Tags: java, sql, list, jdbc, hashset

I would like to ask a more or less opinion-based question, which has arised my interest.
I've been dealing with a project in Java which involves the use of a database (JDBC) and DAOClasses. Suppose my database consists in 4 entities as in the image:

[image]

I have a `readAll` method for every DAOClass which allows me to recover each entry in the database.

My question is: **since each entity entry is defined by it's ID, it is a good practice to collect the result in a `HashSet<T>` over `List<T>` collection type?** (T stands for Type, with can be `Elaborato`, `Assegnazione`, `Studente` or `Docente`).

I would say it is since:

1. No duplicates are allowed in each tables (based on ID);
2. Order does not matter in system workflow;
3. Therefore each `HashSet<T>` has a different and unique element.

Is my assumption correct or there is something which I'm missing?

Comment: generally if you have no duplicates and order is not important, a `Set` is the go-to option. And even when you care about order, you could still use a `TreeSet` which is sorted by `ID`

Comment: @Lino could you elaborate about pros of using `Set` vs `List` in this case - or at least some links? I can't really think why it would be beneficial to use `Set` over `List`. `Set` would only help you ensure that elements are unique which they are anyway, right?

Comment: @Amongalen yes, in this case elements are uniques.

Comment: Really depends on how you're going to use the results -> from pure read perspective - List will be better, considering that you already have unique results, so you don't have to use Set to remove duplicates and as such can skip calculating hashcode for all objects.

Comment: @Amongalen I think about it generally, when the return type of a method is `List` I expect that the `List` can contain duplicate elements. Whereas with a  `Set` I am entirely sure that I will not work with the same element more than once. If one wants to optimize by using a `List` instead of a `Set` because it uses less memory and CPU, then they don't look at the whole thing objectively. Most of the time and memory wasted by the programm is probably simply by accessing the DB..

Comment: @Worthless I haven't thought about the lack of necessity in using `HashSet`, does the unicity of each element makes its use meaningless?

Comment: @Lino that is a valid point - using `Set` simply for the readability. For the access performance anything backed by the HashTable will be optimal I think.

Comment: @Amongalen I think nothing will beat an `ArrayList` for access performance. `Set` implementations have quite a lot of overhead in terms of implementation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel For some reason I've assumed that because `HashSet` is backed by the Hashtable it would perform the same as `HashMap` - O(1) for random access. My assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your purpose with these elements. HashSet consumes about 5.5 times more memory than ArrayList, but it has O(1) time complexity to access an element. So, again, it depends on your purpose.

Comment: A `HashSet` does not have O(1) performance to access an element. It has O(1) performance to check the presence of an element, or to insert one. As `HashSet` does not provide random access, you will need to iterate over it to get any element out of the collection, and that iteration will perform worse than iteration over an `ArrayList`.